# json.net Deserialise to array of objects c#

Tags: c#, arrays, json

I have a POCO class which looks like this:

```
public class Item : Asset
{
    public int PlaylistId { get; set; }
    public int AssetId { get; set; }
    public double Duration { get; set; }
    public int Order { get; set; }
}
```

and **Asset** looks like this:

```
public enum AssetType
{
    Image = 1,
    Video,
    Website
}

public class Asset
{       

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Filename { get; set; }
    public AssetType Type { get; set; }
    public string CreatedById { get; set; }
    public string ModifiedById { get; set; }
    [Display(Name="Created by")] public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
    [Display(Name="Modified by")] public string ModifiedBy { get; set; }
}
```

and then I have a json file which looks like this:

```
{
   "Items":[
      {
         "PlaylistId":1,
         "Type":2,
         "Duration":19,
         "Filename":"stream1_mpeg4.avi"
      },
      {
         "PlaylistId":1,
         "Type":2,
         "Duration":21,
         "Filename":"stream2_mpeg4.avi"
      }
   ]
}
```

and finally I have my code which looks like this:

```
public IList<Item> GetAll()
{
    if (File.Exists(itemsPath))
    {
        using (var fs = new FileStream(itemsPath, FileMode.Open))
        using (var sr = new StreamReader(fs))
        {
            var text = sr.ReadToEnd();
            var array = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Item[]>(sr.ReadToEnd());
            return array.ToList();
        }
    }
    else
        throw new FileNotFoundException("Unable to find the playlist, please make sure that " + itemsPath + " exists.");
}
```

The **text** variable contains the correct json string as I would expect, but the **array** is null, therefore **array.ToList()**; throws an error. 
Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Cheers in advance
/r3plica

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're calling `ReadToEnd()` twice, so the second time there's no more text to read on the stream:

```
var text = sr.ReadToEnd();
var array = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Item[]>(sr.ReadToEnd());
```

just replace the second `sr.ReadToEnd()` with `text` and it should work:

```
var array = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Item[]>(text);
```

Also, as correctly pointed out by @Sachin, your json represent an object with a property called `Items` that is an array or list of `Item` objects.
Therefore, you should pass through an intermediate class as shown in @Sachin's answer, or alternatively using a dictionary, like this:

```
var dict = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string,Item[]>>(text);
var array = dict["Items"];
```

Comment: Yeah, works perfectly and I prefer your method over @Sachin simply because I don't like creating wrapper classes :o

Answer (score 2):

You `json string` represents the serialization of an object which has a `List<Item>` as its property. That means you need to deserialize this string into such an object which has `List<Item>` as a property. So you can make a wrapper class like this

```
public class Wrapper
{
    public List<Item> items { get; set; }
}
```

and then Deserialize it like this

```
var array = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Wrapper>(text);
```

Now you  can see your array has two elements inside it ie. `array.Count=2`